# JSON file with a lot of elements, how to read and print using java?

Tags: java, json

I am very new to JSON. I managed to print out 1 element in the JSON file using Java. However if the file consists of more than 1 element, I do not know how to go about retrieving it. Should I use JSONArray? I tried to search and apply JSONArray, but i got no idea how to. Or does it has something to do with Gson, Jackson thingy? I got no idea what are they..

This is my example.json file:

```
{"rel": "/r/AtLocation", "weight": 0.5, "dataset": "/d/dbpedia/en", "sources": ["/s/dbpedia/3.7"], "id": "/e/ec1914bfb0606c36376fbbcd316e5666022e2469", "features": ["/c/en/apple_inc /r/AtLocation -", "/c/en/apple_inc - /c/en/unite_state", "- /r/AtLocation /c/en/unite_state"], "end": "/c/en/unite_state", "license": "/l/CC/By-SA", "uri": "/a/[/r/AtLocation/,/c/en/apple_inc/,/c/en/unite_state/]", "start": "/c/en/apple_inc", "context": "/ctx/all", "surfaceText": null}
{"rel": "/r/IsA", "weight": 0.5, "dataset": "/d/dbpedia/en", "sources": ["/s/dbpedia/3.7"], "id": "/e/914e6775fd79d660bacf22ec699568e6694da3e8", "features": ["/c/en/america_beautiful /r/IsA -", "/c/en/america_beautiful - /c/en/national_anthem", "- /r/IsA /c/en/national_anthem"], "end": "/c/en/national_anthem", "license": "/l/CC/By-SA", "uri": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/america_beautiful/,/c/en/national_anthem/]", "start": "/c/en/america_beautiful", "context": "/ctx/all", "surfaceText": null}
```

**This is my java file:**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try
        {

            Object obj = parser.parse(
                new FileReader("C:/Users/LijingYeo/Desktop/example.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String rel = (String) jsonObject.get("rel");
            System.out.println(rel);

            String start = (String) jsonObject.get("start");
            System.out.println(start);

            String end = (String) jsonObject.get("end");
            System.out.println(end);

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

All suggestions and helps rendered are sincerely appreciated by me, thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should read your json file line by line and then parse to json object.
This sample code works for your json file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ReadJsonFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        readJsonFile();
    }

    public static void readJsonFile() {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\example.json"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Record:\t" + sCurrentLine);

                Object obj;
                try {
                    obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                    String rel = (String) jsonObject.get("rel");
                    System.out.println(rel);

                    String start = (String) jsonObject.get("start");
                    System.out.println(start);

                    String end = (String) jsonObject.get("end");
                    System.out.println(end);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Json file is yours as below. I hope this may help.

Comment: Your json file is not json object but writing json objects line by line.

Comment: OMG. I thank you for your help @sweson! You make me feel confident to carry on with my work! Cheers to you!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing is right.

Your JSON structure is of type `JSONObject`, i.e (Key, Value) pairs. Of those elements, `features` element's value is of type `JSONArray`. So while browsing through the elements, you should cast the value of `features` element to `JSONArray` and then iterate through the list of elements in that array.

```
JSONArray features = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("features");
int size = features.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    System.out.println(features.get(i));
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Hi @Vikdor, I got this error: The method length() is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: What JSON parser library are you using? I was referring to `JSONArray` from http://www.json.org/java/index.html. Can you check the equivalent of `length()` method for the `JSONArray` in your library? something like `size()` etc.,?

Comment: Sure Sir! I thank you for your help! I will read up and check! I am using json.simple library.. is that the library name you are looking for? I cant really converse well in programming language, especially JSON. ): My bad.. Sorry!

Comment: OKay. json.simple's JSONArray has `size()` method to get the length of the array. Updated the code snippet in my answer accordingly.

Comment: size() works, but the print out is abit weird. I have modified my .json file. Just now i only show you 1 element, now there is 2 elements..

Comment: Your entire JSON document should be a valid JSON object, i.e. either a `JSONObject` (map) which means everthing should be within `{ }` or a `JSONArray` (array) within `[]`. So, enclose those two maps in an array. Then, upon parsing, the JSONObject returned will be of type `JSONArray` and each element in that array is a `JSONObject`. Hope you got this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html).

```
String jsonString = null;
if (prettyPrint == true) {
    // this is time consuming
    jsonString = myObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myObject);
} else {
    // faster option
    jsonString = myObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
}
```